# Can open circuits have 0 potential difference?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transient

[image: rc circuit]

So I do know that the capacitor will be an open circuit at t < 0 (also at t > 0) since it is connected to a DC source. But since at t < 0, the switch is also open, meaning i will have another open circuit. What will happen to Vc? Will it be 0 volts? Or will it be the negative of the voltage across the 5 ohm resistor?

Comment: The voltage Vc at T < 0 is an initial condition whose value is not specified. Question cannot be answered without knowing that. I think you need a better question.

Comment: The only possible answer to your SE post is that the problem you've been assigned is defective and unanswerable as it fails to state the initial conditions.  And please do not misuse tags, this has absolutely nothing to do with "remote-control".  If you have to complete an assignment before you can discuss this with the professor, start with a statement of what is wrong with the question then state that you will be solving it for the initial condition of Vc = 0 since that would be the simplest case.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that comment : especially, report, assume and state the assumption : is the only possible answer.

Comment: Chris is correct. The statement of the problem basically says the circuit reached steady-state before \$t=0\$, so the capacitor voltage could in general be calculated. But in this particular problem, you can't. There's no unique solution. For example, how can you tell me it's wrong to say the initial capacitor voltage is 0 V or -20 V? You can't refute it!

But to at least solve the circuit, assume the capacitor's voltage is \$v_c(0) = V_0\$. In other words, work with a symbolic solution. If the professor says to assume whatever value, simply change the value of \$V_0\$ at the end.

Comment: I guess one could leave the initial voltage as a variable in the solution...

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorrry about the tag, it was supposed to be rc-circuits but it got auto replaced. I'm new to the forum, still learning the way around here.Also, i think ill try going with the leaving the initial voltage as a variable in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is not really clear what is meant by the statement that 'the switch was open for a long time' ideal capacitors are charged or not charged to a certain voltage. Assuming that they mean that the voltage on the capacitor is zero volts, I wrote the following answer to your question.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM2oGc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_1+\text{n}\cdot\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_1+\text{n}\cdot\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1\right)
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\text{n}\cdot\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\text{n}\cdot\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1\right)
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Using the first and the and the second equation of the system of equations, given in \$(3)\$, we can solve for \$\text{V}_1\$:

$$\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\text{n}\cdot\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\text{V}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{n}\text{R}_1\right)}{\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{n}\text{R}_2\right)\right)}\tag4$$

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag5$$
- The input voltage, \$\text{V}_\text{i}\$, is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\tag6$$

So, we can rewrite equation \$(4)\$ as follows:

$$\text{v}_1\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\cdot\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(1+\text{n}\text{R}_1\right)}{\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(1+\text{n}\text{R}_2\right)\right)}\tag7$$

Using your values and Mathematica I found that:

$$\text{V}_1\left(t\right)=\frac{9}{4}\cdot\left(1-\exp\left(-40000t\right)\right)\tag8$$

With the following Mathematica-codes:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{(V1/R2) + (V1/R3) == ((Vi - V1)/R1) + n*(Vi - V1)}, V1]]

Out[1]={{V1 -> (R2 R3 (Vi + n R1 Vi))/(R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R2 R3))}}

In[2]:=Vi = u/s;
u = 3;
R3 = 1/(s*c);
c = 20*10^(-6);
R1 = 10;
R2 = 5;
n = 1/2;
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[(R2 R3 (Vi + n R1 Vi))/(
  R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R2 R3)), s, t]]

Out[2]=9/4 - (9 E^(-40000 t))/4
```

> So, we can answer your questions:
>
> 1. When we want to find \$\text{V}_1\left(0^+\right)\$, we get:
>    $$\text{V}_1\left(0^+\right)=\frac{9}{4}\cdot\left(1-\exp\left(-40000\cdot0\right)\right)=0\space\text{V}\tag9$$
> 2. When we want to find \$\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{V}_1\left(t\right)\$, we get:
>    $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{V}_1\left(t\right)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{9}{4}\cdot\left(1-\exp\left(-40000t\right)\right)=\frac{9}{4}=2.25\space\text{V}\tag{10}$$
> 3. The time constant is given by:
>    $$\tau=\frac{1}{40000}=0.000025\space\text{s}\tag{11}$$

---

**EDIT**

When we solve this \$\text{V}_1\$ in the general case we get:

$$\text{V}_1\left(t\right)=\frac{\text{R}_2\hat{\text{u}}(\text{n}\text{R}_1+1)\left(1-\exp\left(-t\cdot\frac{\text{n}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}\right)\right)}{\text{n}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag{12}$$

Using the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[3]:=Vi = u/s;
R3 = 1/(s*c);
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[(R2 R3 (Vi + n R1 Vi))/(
  R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R2 R3)), s, t]]

Out[3]=((1 - E^(-(((R1 + R2 + n R1 R2) t)/(c R1 R2)))) (1 + 
   n R1) R2 u)/(R1 + R2 + n R1 R2)
```

So, for \$\tau\$ we get:

$$\tau=\frac{\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{n}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag{13}$$

So, for \$(12)\$ you will get:

$$\text{V}_1\left(\tau\right)=\frac{\text{R}_2\hat{\text{u}}(\text{n}\text{R}_1+1)\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{n}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\cdot\frac{\text{n}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}\right)\right)}{\text{n}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}=$$
$$\frac{\text{R}_2\hat{\text{u}}(\text{n}\text{R}_1+1)\left(1-\exp\left(-1\right)\right)}{\text{n}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag{14}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you've gotten tau. What total resistance did you use? I tried plugging in the parallel and series combination of the resistors and didn't get anywhere near 25micro s. And wouldn't tau just be RC and not 1/RC?

Comment: Also, with your circuit diagram, why do you have an R3?

Comment: @Duts Look at my edit. Notice that later in my answer I transform (using Laplace) the resistor \$\text{R}_3\$ into a capacitor using \$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\$. And notice that \$\tau\$ is found when the function in the exponential function is equal to \$-1\$.

Comment: I quite don't get laplace transform yet as we haven't tackled it yet (will be our next lesson). But from intuition, I did see what you have done with R3. But I still can't understand how you got tau. Also, thanks! Ill go back to this after we finish laplace.

Comment: @Duts first take your class about Laplace Transform, after that take another class: circuit analysis and you will learn how to compute \$\tau\$, and learn what the effect of it is on the value of the function at that point. Third piece of advice, study mathematics and learn how to program in Mathematica to check your calculations and verify them by using LTspice for example.

Comment: I think I got it now how you got tau. I just remembered that we have a dependent source and Rth is not as simple as the parallel/series combination of Rs. We are also working with LTspice now! Ill try to look ito mathematica too. Thank you!

Comment: @Duts you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

"The switch is open for a very long time" indicates that the capacitor will have had enough time to loose all charge (parasitic resistance, leakage current - both properties of all real capacitors).

That just means that \$V_c\$ will be 0 V right before \$t = 0\$.

I'm not sure that thinking in open circuits is helping here - a capacitor can be substituted with an open circuit in some cases, but this task is not one of them as it deals with the time domain analysis of the circuit.

Comment: I have attended a safety briefing after someone mistakenly made that assumption about a rather larger capacitor. The essence of the briefing was: don't make that assumption.

Comment: This is a theoretical teaching question not a practical one, if there were leakage, there'd be a resistor modeling it.  The question is **defective and unansweable** because the teacher forget to state the initial conditions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you might argue that. I've described the way I have learned to solve the problems in the way it satisfies the professor. Sure the wording could be clearer if it just stated that Vc is 0 for t < 0, but meh, old habits die slow, so these questions will be around for another decade or two.

Comment: @BrianDrummond the time was obviously not long enough.

Comment: There's really no valid assumption of Vc=0 as a matter of theory.   If one wants to solve the problem that way because it's impossible to get clarification from the teaching staff before the homework is due, then the solution needs to start with a statement of the fact that the question is unanswerable before preceding to state that the problem will be solved for the simple case which would occur if the initial condition of Vc=0 were given.

Comment: @Arsenal Okay. I've fixed the problem for everyone concerned: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RofR.png). Now we can all go home and rest easy.